# Elementary Cube vs. Elementary Chain

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading *Computational Homology* by Kaczynski, Mischaikow, and Mrozek. On page 47, for every elementary cube, $Q \in \mathcal{K}_k^d$ they associate an object $\widehat{Q}$ that they call an elementary $k$-chain. They say that this association mimicks what was done earlier in the book where they defined a chain. But to define a chain, they took a combinatorial graph $G = (\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})$ and constructed a vector space, $C_0(G;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ by using $\mathcal{V}$ as a basis for this space. As such, each $c \in C_0(G;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ can be written as
$$c = \alpha_1 \widehat{v}_1 + \alpha_2 \widehat{v}_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n \widehat{v}_n,$$
where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\widehat{v}_i$ is just the combinatorial object associated with the vertex $v_i \in \mathcal{V}$. Now they refer to this expression as a chain.

So how can we mimick this process for elementary cubes to define an elementary $k$-chain? How is an elementary $k$-chain represented?

Take $Q = [0,1]^2$ for instance. What exactly is $\widehat{Q}$?